# When is a proper map closed?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples

In [Page 53](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BDoAPUctz-UC&lpg=PA93&vq=proper%20action&pg=PA53#v=onepage&q&f=false) of "Lie Groups" by Duistermaat and Kolk, we find the following:

> A map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ between topological spaces is *proper* if $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact for each compact $K\subseteq Y$.

It is then claimed that if $X$ and $Y$ are Hausdorff then $f$ is a closed map (that is, if $C\subseteq X$ is closed then $f(C)$ is closed in $Y$).

I have not been able to prove this.  In various locations, you can find a proof that if $Y$ is Hausdorff and locally compact then proper implies closed (e.g. [this answer on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1604210/1438)).

Is this result true just under the Hausdorff condition?  If not, what is a counter-example?

Comment: just a note, in two of my books proper maps are by definition closed, so it's interesting/weird that your book doesn't define it that way. Anyone know which definition is more natural?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true if you merely assume $Y$ is Hausdorff (or even if you assume both $X$ and $Y$ are Hausdorff).  For instance, let $S$ be an uncountable set and fix an element $a\in S$.  Let $Y$ be $S$ with the topology such that a set is open iff it is either cocountable or does not contain $a$.  Let $X$ be $S$ with the discrete topology.  Then $X$ and $Y$ are Hausdorff, and the identity map $f:X\to Y$ is proper since every compact subset of $Y$ is finite.  However, $f$ is not closed.

(More generally, you could take $Y$ to be any Hausdorff space which is not compactly generated and let $f:X\to Y$ be its $k$-ification.  So, combining this with Stefan Hamcke's answer at the linked question, a necessary and sufficient condition for this theorem to be valid for a Hausdorff space $Y$ is that $Y$ is compactly generated.)

Comment: $Y$ and $X$ are even hereditarily normal, so separation axioms won't make a better result possible. And $Y$ is even only *not* locally compact at $a$, and $X$ *is* locally compact, so it's pretty close to optimal.